# how to pre-fill select box in typo3 backend

Tags: php, typo3

First of all excuse my bad english.

I got a problem with my select-field in the BE. I would like to prefill (preselect) all of the available items.

Code in ext_tables.php:

```
'teilnehmer' => array(
        'exclude' => 0,
        'label' => 'LLL:EXT:kiwanisext/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_kiwanisext_domain_model_veranstaltung.teilnehmer',
        'config' => array(
            'type' => 'select',
            'foreign_table' => 'fe_users',
            'MM' => 'tx_kiwanisext_veranstaltung_user_mm',
            'size' => 10,
            'autoSizeMax' => 30,
            'maxitems' => 9999,
            'multiple' => 0,
            'wizards' => array(
                '_PADDING' => 1,
                '_VERTICAL' => 1,
                'edit' => array(
                    'type' => 'popup',
                    'title' => 'Edit',
                    'script' => 'wizard_edit.php',
                    'icon' => 'edit2.gif',
                    'popup_onlyOpenIfSelected' => 1,
                    'JSopenParams' => 'height=350,width=580,status=0,menubar=0,scrollbars=1',
                    ),
                'add' => Array(
                    'type' => 'script',
                    'title' => 'Create new',
                    'icon' => 'add.gif',
                    'params' => array(
                        'table' => 'fe_users',
                        'pid' => '###CURRENT_PID###',
                        'setValue' => 'prepend'
                        ),
                    'script' => 'wizard_add.php',
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
```

I found nothing helpful in the documentation.

Any hint, tip or help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not possible to do that with plain TCA config, afaik. You can however define a default value wich will be selected (if none is defines, 1st item will be selected).

```
'default' => 'myValue'
```

But to preselect multiple values at once, you have to use JavaScript I guess.

Answer (score 1):

This code worked for me in typo3 6.2. I have a selectbox  filled with database records.
I want the records with ID's 1 ans 2 to be preselected in the selectbox:

```
'thematique' => array(
    'exclude' => 0,     
    'label' => 'LLL:EXT:dk_actus/locallang_db.xml:tx_dkactus_thematique',       
    'config' => array(
        'type' => 'select',
        'foreign_table' => 'tx_dkactus_thematique', 
        'foreign_table_where' => 'ORDER BY tx_dkactus_thematique.uid',
        'size' => 10,
        'minitems' => 0,
        'maxitems' => 99,
        'default' => '1,2',
    ),
),
```